# Is there a way to specify the column order for a many-many table when EF Code first creates it?

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following mapping:

```
public webpages_RolesMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.RoleId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.RoleName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(256);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("webpages_Roles");
            this.Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
            this.Property(t => t.RoleName).HasColumnName("RoleName");

            // Relationships
            this.HasMany(t => t.UserProfiles)
                .WithMany(t => t.webpages_Roles)
                .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
                        m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                        m.MapRightKey("UserId");
                    });

        }
```

When I use Code First then this forces EF to create a webpages_UsersInRoles table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles](
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleId] ASC,
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

However the SimpleMembership classes created by Microsoft perform inserts that do not specify the column names and it expects the first column to be UserID and the second RoleId.

```
INSERT INTO webpages_UsersInRoles VALUES (1,3);
```

How can I make the mapping above create a table where UserID is column 1 and RoleId is column 2 ?

Note that I already tried adding this:

```
public partial class UsersInRoles
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

}
```

But is seems to ignore this and still create the many to many with column names in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must configure the many-to-many relationship from the other side to change the column order:

```
// UserProfileMap derived from EntityTypeConfiguration<UserProfile>
public UserProfileMap() 
{
    // ...
    this.HasMany(t => t.webpages_Roles)
        .WithMany(t => t.UserProfiles)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
        });
}
```